# How to create a generic service in Aurelia Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, aurelia

I'm currently using Aurelia as my front end framework and Typescript. I have 5 entities with basic crud functionalities. How can I create a generic service so I won't create 5 files with the same functionalities? This is what I have so far. Would be great if I could transform it to a generic type and just pass the api url. Thanks

```
import { HttpClient, json } from "aurelia-fetch-client";
import { inject } from "aurelia-framework";

@inject(HttpClient)
export class WheelTypeService {
    public wheelTypes: WheelType[];
    private http: HttpClient;

    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
        http.configure(config => config.useStandardConfiguration());
        this.http = http;
    }

    getAll() {
        var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (!this.wheelTypes) {
                this.http.fetch('/api/WheelTypes')
                    .then(result => result.json() as Promise<WheelType[]>)
                    .then(data => {
                        this.wheelTypes= data;
                        resolve(this.wheelTypes);
                    })
                    .catch(err => reject(err));
            } else resolve(this.wheelTypes);
        });

        return promise;
    }
 // omitted some of the crud functionalities
}
```

Comment: The correct answer is to use decorators. You would still need to create a class per type, but you could add the functions needed using a decorator.

That being said, creating decorators can be a bit confusing, so I'll refrain from providing an answer unless you want me to show how to do it, as it is a bit involved to do, but easy to use once created.. for the most part.

Comment: Please show me how to do it. This may be the answer I was looking for. Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic example using generics and typescript. The interfaces should match the structure of the json that is returned by the api. Hope this is helpful...

```
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";
import { HttpClient } from "aurelia-http-client";

export interface IReturnType1 {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export interface IReturnType2 {
    id: number;
    height: string;
    weight: string;
}

@autoinject
export class GenericService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getOne<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
        return this.http
            .get(url)
            .then(response => response.content);
    }

    getAll<T>(url: string): Promise<T[]> {
        return this.http
            .get(url)
            .then(response => response.content);
    }
}

@autoinject
export class ConsumerExample {
    constructor(private svc: GenericService) { }

    async getAllReturnType1(){
        const result = await this.svc.getAll<IReturnType1>("url/for/request/1");
    }

    async getOneReturnType2(){
        const result = await this.svc.getOne<IReturnType2>("url/for/request/2");
    }
}
```

Inheritance example...

```
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";
import { HttpClient } from "aurelia-http-client";

export interface IReturnType1 {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export interface IReturnType2 {
    id: number;
    height: string;
    weight: string;
}

export interface IRequestUrls {
    getOne: string;
    getAll: string;
}

@autoinject
export abstract class GenericService<T> {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    abstract urls: IRequestUrls;

    getOne(): Promise<T> {
        return this.http
            .get(this.urls.getOne)
            .then(response => response.content);
    }

    getAll(): Promise<T[]> {
        return this.http
            .get(this.urls.getAll)
            .then(response => response.content);
    }
}

export class Request1 extends GenericService<IReturnType1> {
    urls: {
        getOne: "/url/for/request/1";
        getAll: "/url/for/request/1/all";
    };
}

export class Request2 extends GenericService<IReturnType2> {
    urls: {
        getOne: "/url/for/request/2";
        getAll: "/url/for/request/2/all";
    };
}

@autoinject
export class ConsumerExample {
    constructor(
        private r1: Request1,
        private r2: Request2
    ) { }

    async getAllReturnType1() {
        const result = await this.r1.getAll();
    }

    async getOneReturnType2() {
        const result = await this.r2.getOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. So you let the consumer pass the urlapi.

Comment: Yeah, that's a simple way to do it if that works for you. Another idea could be to use inheritance (added to above example)

Comment: do you think you can add a sample consumer using inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already had a look into https://github.com/SpoonX/aurelia-orm? I think, this is what you are looking for:

Your `WheelType` may change to something like this:

```
@resource('/api/WheelTypes') // important point
export class WheelType {
  ...
}
```

In your View-Model you would do:

```
@inject(EntityManager)
export class WheelTypeVM {
    constructor(entityManager) {
      this.repository = entityManager.getRepository('user');
    }

    // your CRUD comes here, e.g.
    getAll() {
      return this.repository.find()
        .then(data => {
           this.wheelTypes = data;
        });
    }
}
```

This is just a small excerpt, there is some other stuff to do (Plugin Configuration). However, you would save the services for each of your entity (or you could even wrap the code in the VM and use generics).

Comment: Thanks. Will check this